# Why is Everyone Choosing JSON Over XML for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, json

I thought XML is highly portable and can be used as a mini database. I have seen XML used everywhere. I even see large companies switching over to [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Even Microsoft has integrated support for JSON. What is all the hype over JSON?

Comment: "everyone" and "everywhere" are such absolute terms...

Comment: @eliben XML actually doesn't suck. It's very powerful but just like hunting rabits with a rocket launcher, it may not always be the best option.

Comment: Most of what people are currently using XML for would be better off in JSON

Comment: @Dan If only XML was as much fun as hunting rabbits with a rocket launcher (presumably - I can't say I've tried it myself)

Comment: because its 'The Fat-Free Alternative to XML' -json.org

Comment: Because not many browsers support E4X

Comment: JavaScript Object Notation. The first hint is the name.

Comment: @Dan: No, it really DOES suck (XML that is)..  I hate it with a passion.  Never understood the need for that bloat.  I am not sold on JSON yet either but it is, at the least, easier to consume.

Comment: Because of KISS.  XML adds extra layers of abstraction since every element has an array of children and a dictionary of attributes.  In JSON every element is a primitive, an array or a dictionary.

Comment: @ David Johnstone: I have to ask why you wouldnt use a rocket launcher when rabbit hunting if you could? More fun and greater ranger of use in the end, never know when a bear might wander out... ;)

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Basically because JSON is recognized natively by JavaScript, it's really lightweight, minimalistic and highly portable because it relies only on two fundamental structures:

- A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
- An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Comment: +1.. really.. so many different datatypes support matters a lot compared to raw xml text

Comment: +1, especially since JSON parsing is unbelievably more efficient compared to XML parsing, even piecewise. Once the datasets you care about exceed a certain (and frighteningly small) threshold, the performance difference is noticeable.

Comment: Somebody show me data that says JSON parsing is faster than XML in modern browsers.  An answer on SO here says otherwise:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596465/is-parsing-json-faster-than-parsing-xml

Answer (score 137):

XML doesn't really begin to shine until you start mixing together different namespaced schemas.  Then you see JSON start to fall down, but if you just need a serialization format for your data, JSON is smaller, lighterweight, more human readable, and generally faster than XML.

Comment: +1 for showing what XML is really useful for.  Too often people use XML even when they could get by with something much simpler.

Comment: Yeah going to have to agree with jcd and Daniel here.  Quality response on why XML is still pretty good for some things.

Comment: How is XML less readable,  I find it almost impossible to read json where I think the hierarchy of XML is much more understandable (certainly a little wordy).  Perhaps I just haven't worked enough with JSON

Comment: namespaces are an xml solution to solve certain problems when you do things with XML.
If you are using json, find a *json* solution to solve those same problems in the json way.
To me the namespaces argument is just like "Oh ! but json does not have attributes !"

Answer (score 61):

I find that a big benefit of JSON over XML is that I don't have to decide how to format the data. As some have shown, there are numerous ways to do even simple data structures in XML -- as elements, as attribute values, etc. Then you have to document it, write up XML Schema or Relax NG or some other crap... It's a mess.

XML may have its merits, but for basic data interchange, JSON is much more compact and direct. As a Python developer, there is no impedance mismatch between the simple data types in JSON and in Python. So if I was writing a server-side handler for an AJAX query that was asking about snow conditions for a particular Ski resort, I would build up a dictionary like follows:

```
conditions = {
    'new_snow_24': 5.0,
    'new_snow_48': 8.5,
    'base_depth': 88.0,
    'comments': 'Deep and steep!',
    'chains_required': True,
}
return simplejson.dumps(conditions)   # Encode and dump `conditions` as a JSON string
```

When translated through JSON (using a library like 'simplejson' for Python), the resulting JSON structure looks nearly identical (except in JSON, booleans are lower-cased).

Decoding that structure only requires a JSON parser, whether it's for Javascript or Objective-C for a native iPhone app or C# or a Python client. The floats would get interpreted as floats, the strings as strings, and booleans as booleans. Using the 'simplejson' library in Python, a `simplejson.loads(some_json_string)` statement would give me back a full data structure like I just made in the above example.

If I wrote XML, I'd have to decide whether to do elements or attributes. Both of the following are valid:

```
<conditions>
    <new-snow-24>5</new-snow-24>
    <new-snow-48>8.5</new-snow-48>
    <chains-required>yes</chains-required>
    <comments>deep and steep!</comments>
</conditions>

<conditions newSnow24="5" newSnow48="8.5" chainsRequired="yes">
   <comments>deep and steep!</comments>
</conditions>
```

So not only do I have to think about the data that I may want to send to the client, I have to think about how to format it. XML, while simpler than plain SGML by being more strict with its rules, still provides too many ways to think about that data. Then I would have to go about generating it. I could not just take a Python dictionary (or other simple data structure) and say "go make thyself into my XML". I could not receive an XML document and immediately say "go make thyself into objects and data structures" without writing a custom parser, or without requiring the additional overhead of XML Schema/Relax NG and other such pains.

The short of it is that it's just much easier and much more direct to encode and decode data to JSON, especially for quick interchanges. This may apply more to people coming from a dynamic language background, as the basic data types (lists, dictionaries, etc) built in to JavaScript / JSON directly map to the same or similar data types in Python, Perl, Ruby, etc.

Answer (score 33):

The performance of JSON isn't much different from XML for most use cases, JSON isn't well suited and
readable for deeply nest structures... you will run into ]]]}], which makes debugging difficult

Answer (score 31):

It's lightweight compared to XML. If you need to scale, reduce your bandwidth requirements!

Compare JSON

```
 [
      {
           color: "red",
           value: "#f00"
      },
      {
           color: "green",
           value: "#0f0"
      },
      {
           color: "blue",
           value: "#00f"
      },
      {
           color: "cyan",
           value: "#0ff"
      },
      {
           color: "magenta",
           value: "#f0f"
      },
      {
           color: "yellow",
           value: "#ff0"
      },
      {
           color: "black",
           value: "#000"
      }
 ]
```

to XML:

```
 <colors>
      <color >
           <name>red</name>
           <value>#f00</value>
      </color>
      <color >
           <name>green</name>
           <value>#0f0</value>
      </color>
      <color >
           <name>blue</name>
           <value>#00f</value>
      </color>
      <color >
           <name>cyan</name>
           <value>#0ff</value>
      </color>
      <color >
           <name>magenta</name>
           <value>#f0f</value>
      </color>
      <color >
           <name>yellow</name>
           <value>#ff0</value>
      </color>
      <color >
           <name>black</name>
           <value>#000</value>
      </color>
 </colors>
```

Comment: not just smaller, but more human friendly.  XML looks like a poor attempt of a human to talk like a computer.

Comment: Your XML can also reduce the XML wtih attributes instead of elements for simple types (name/value)

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, but then it looks inconsistent and ugly. And you still need open/close tags for the element. JSON (at best) halves the number of tags you need to use.

Comment: Look at Marc's example. I don't see how you version is easier to read than his. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743532/why-is-everyone-choosing-json-over-xml-for-jquery/1743664#1743664

Comment: difference is length doesn't seem that big to me

Comment: @Jimmy  It's more than just length-- what if this was a test configuration file for a website?  I sure wouldn't want to write or edit the XML version-- too many redundant keystrokes or time spent flipping through the reference manual to relearn how the XML-aware features work.  The JSON version is much easier to manage.

Comment: A small note, but the JSON isn't valid: You need some `"` around those strings. (The keys in your map.)

Comment: Why do we care when its compressed anyway?

Answer (score 28):

Just an anecdote from my own personal experience:

I wrote a small Javascript directory, first with the data in XML, and then adapted it to use JSON so I could run them side-by-side and compare speeds with Firebug. The JSON ended up being approximately 3 times faster (350-400 ms vs. 1200-1300 ms to display all data). Also, as others have noted, the JSON is much easier on the eyes and the file size was a good 25% smaller due to the leaner markup.

Comment: If everybody created these benchmarks, we'd have nothing to argue about though.

Answer (score 20):

```
 <colors>
      <color name='red'     value='#f00'/>
      <color name='green'   value='#0f0'/>
      <color name='blue'    value='#00f'/>
      <color name='cyan'    value='#0ff'/>
      <color name='magenta' value='#f0f'/>
      <color name='yellow'  value='#ff0'/>
      <color name='black'   value='#000'/>
 </colors>
```

With attributes, XML is nice. But for some reason, home-made XML is generally 100% made of elements, and ugly.

Comment: That is still more non-whitespace chars than the JSON example. And parsing attributes can be more annoying in XML.

Comment: Probably because complex types can really only be described in elements so that how most tools default.  I agree that this XML is very simple to use and read.

Answer (score 18):

Easy consumption by JavaScript can be one of the reasons ..

Comment: That's the big reason I use it. Parsing xml manually is nightmarishly complex. Also, since I use Python to create the JSON in the first place, they handle data and objects in a very similar way, meaning serialization back and forth makes everything happy!

Answer (score 10):

JSON is best for consumption of data in web applications from webservices for its size and ease of use, especially due to the built-in support in [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). Imagine the computation overhead for parsing an xml fragment compared to the instant lookup in JSON.

A very good example is JSON-P. You can get back data from a webservice wrapped in a callback function call, like `my_callback({"color": "blue", "shape":"square"});` inside a dynamically generated `<script>` tag so the data can be directly consumed in the function `my_callback()`. There is no way to get even close to this convenience using XML.

XML would be the format of choice for large documents, where you have a framework of rendering pages of data in multiple formats using XSLT. XML can also be used with application configuration files for readability among many other uses.

Answer (score 8):

No one here has mentioned XML-s main advantage: validation rules (DTD, XSD). My conclusions, having used both:

- JSON is perfect for ajax, especially if you develop both server and client side yourself. You basically create js objects right in your server script!
- XML shines in corporate environments, when you have to set data exchange standards between big bureaucratic organizations. Often, one party develops its part months before another, so it really benefits from validating its requests against agreed XSD. Also, in big corporations, data transfer is often translated between different systems. This is also XML's strength, think XSLT. Example: code-free conversion into JSON :p

Of course, there's json-schema being developed but you won't find built-in support for it anywhere.

I'm a fanboy of both, they have just different strengths.

Answer (score 6):

Now that there are JSON encoders and decoders for most languages, there's no reason NOT to use JSON for uses where it makes sense (and that's probably 90% of the use cases for XML).

I've even heard of JSON strings being used in large SQL databases to make schema changes easier.

Answer (score 5):

JSON has no impedance-mismatch with JavaScript programming. JSON can contain integers, strings, lists, arrays. XML is just elements and nodes that need to be parsed into integers and so on before it can be consumed.

Comment: The need to parse items does not equate to an impedence mismatch.

Comment: An impedence mismatch is when concepts don't map cleanly from one format to another, as with object-relational mapping.  Some things are very easy to express with objects but hard with SQL while other things are easy to express using SQL, but object hierarchies have a hard time expressing them clearly.  With XML and JSON, one often requires a bit more work to get to the meaning than the other, but that really depends on the parsing tools.  The expressiveness is (mostly) the same.

Answer (score 5):

Quite honestly, there isn't so much that's different between JSON and XML in the fact that they can represent all types of data.  However, XML is syntactically bigger than JSON and that makes it heavier than JSON.

Comment: didn't find your answer particularly inspiring, but it wasn't wrong so a down votes seemed unjust.

Comment: +1 for stating that XML can be used in a way to be a *proper* superset of JSON.

Answer (score 4):

Both are great and very portable. However JSON has been gaining popularity since it serializes into less characters in most cases (which translates into a faster delivery time) and since it matches the JavaScript object syntax it can be directly translated into an in-memory object which makes [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) a lot easier to implement.

XML is still great. JSON's just the "latest and greatest" compared to XML.

Comment: And I believe that newer revisions of JavaScript are beginning to include "safe" (eval-free) built-in JSON encoders and decoders.

Answer (score 4):

Easily parsed by JavaScript and it is lightweight (a document in JSON is smaller than a XML document that contain the same data.)

Answer (score 3):

JSON is effectively serialized JavaScript in that you can eval(aJsonString) directly into a JavaScript object. Inside of a browser it's a no-brainer JSON is perfectly suited for JavaScript. At the same time JavaScript is a very loosely-typed dynamic language and cannot natively take advantage of all the specific type information available contained within an Xml/Xsd document. This extra metadata (which is great for interoperability) is  a hinderance in JavaScript making it more tedious and cubersome to work with.

**Size vs Performance**

If you're in a browser JSON is faster to serialize/deserialize as it's simpler, more compact and more importantly natively supported. I have some [northwind database benchmarks available](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.100000-times.2010-08-17.html) comparing the size and speed between the different serializers available. In the Base Class Library Microsoft's XML DataContract serializer is over **30%** faster than their JSON one. Although this has more to do with the effort Microsoft put into their XML serializer as I was able to develop a [JsonSerializer](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) that is more than **2.6x** faster than their XML one. As for payloads based on the benchmarks it looks as though XML is roughly more than **2x** the size of JSON. However this can quickly blow out if your XML payload uses many different namespaces within the same document.

Answer (score 2):

XML is bloated snake oil in most situations. JSON gives you most of the benefits without the bloat.

Answer (score 1):

One major advantage other than the ones mentioned here.
For the same data, there are multiple ways to represent it as a XML file but only one way with JSON, removes ambiguity :)

Comment: `{"colors":["red","green","blue"],"systems":["windows","mac"]}` vs. `{"entries":[{"type":"color","value":"red"},{"type":"system","value":"mac"}]}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert by far but from the various companies I've worked for we generally use XML in small data environments or configuration values (web.config is a great example).

When you have large amounts of data, generally, you will want to report on that data.  And XML is not a great source for reporting.  In the grand scheme of things, it seems as though a transactional database is easier to report/search against than XML.

Does this make sense?  As I said above, I'm no expert but from my experience this seems to be the case.  Also, I believe Microsoft integrated JSON support due to the wave of developers moving over to client-side or scripted actions to enhance the visuals of the UI ([Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)) and Microsoft's Ajax has not been used as much as other libraries like jQuery and [MooTools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MooTools) (Yahoo's [YUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library) is also in that mix) due to their beautiful integration of serializable objects using JSON.

I find myself writing code now implementing the JSON serializer in my VB code.  It's WAY too easy and from an upgrading/modifying standpoint, you can't beat it.  It's Microsoft's way of keeping us addicted to VS I guess.  I have recently converted an enterprise application to using Ajax (via jQuery) and using JSON format.  It took approximately 2 weeks to do so.  I actually thank Microsoft for integrating it because without it, I would have had to write quite a bit of extra code.

Comment: I think there was some confusion over the question and this answer contains a lot of speculation.

Comment: @Eric P: absolutely nothing wrong with VB.