# Which one is faster to parse data Json or XML in web services?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, xml-parsing

Previously I used XML soap for data exchange in my web services, But it taking so much time  to display data.

In what case would you need to use XML or json for web service response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely JSON. Try this library - https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Also, this is probably a duplicate of [Is parsing JSON faster than parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596465/is-parsing-json-faster-than-parsing-xml) .

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a far better web response service than XML.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use JSON web service.. You'll find its significance over SOAP web service once you use it..

Answer (score 0):

JSON is always faster than XML.

You should go through [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) link for more information.