# NSURLConnection too slow

Tags: ios, xml, nsurlconnection

I am using an `NSURLConnection` in my app where I scan a barcode, send the XML via the `NSURLConnection` and the java service sends me back an XML. 
My problem here is that with Wifi, the response time is decent, but when I use 3G, it's freaking slow.

How can I manage to fasten things up in 3G?

```
  NSString *xmlHomeMade = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version='1.0'?>"
                         "<service name='CorePDAService' method='blahblah'>"
                         "<arg class='java.lang.String'>%@</arg>"
                         "</service>",cab];


NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *ipAgence = [defaults objectForKey:@"ipAgence"];

NSLog(@"agence IP Test : %@",ipAgence);


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:ipAgence];


NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [xmlHomeMade length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:10];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [xmlHomeMade dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error] ;


if(urlResponse == nil){

    if (error) {

        [self displayAlert:@"" message:@"Error"];

    }

}


NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


[self parseXML:data];
```

Comment: It sounds more like network bottleneck. How much data does your app  upload/download per request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is implicit.

3G is a cellular technology which suffers a lot more from network nasties like Jitter & Latency than your WiFi connection (which is probably ADSL, VDSL or cable).

In particular (due to the way 3G is implemented) when it begins to create a connection it has to request network resources and allocate a channel (it's a lot more complicated than that - but it's basically the jist, I used to be a developer for a telecoms hardware provider).

**The only real way to "speed" up a 3G connection is to either a) slim down the payload or b) keep an active connection (radio access barer) consistently.**

3G as a technology is high latency and bursty. One you begin a burst it usually operates at reasonable pace (relatively) but when creating the connection initially there is some serious latency.

When the connection is inactive for a period of time it will drop the resources it was granted by the radio network controllers, and re-requesting this is part of the slow down.

Comment: I meant that I want to know if there's a way to reduce time, such as using a socket so it reduces the time to establish connection each times... Stuffs like that

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I'm saying - using a consistently connected socket WILL absolutely increase the speed and responsiveness of your network activities.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to use a socket ? Some examples ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this issue for, I can't tell how long! Today I learnt that I can use `gzip` compression to fasten up things. To use this, you need to have it installed on the server, and the good news is if you're using `apache2` on your server, it comes by default. To test to make sure your server/URL had `gzip` compression enabled, test it with this online tool:
http://www.feedthebot.com/tools/gzip/

If the answer is yes, proceed to add the code to your Objective-C code in Xcode. After this line in your code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

just add this other line:

```
[theRequest addValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
```

This will speed up your response time noticeably, and you do not need to use `AFNetworking` for a small `NSURLRequest` or `NSURLConnection` task.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm not working on this project anymore but that's the idea, I compressed the XML and I had better time responses. Though, I don't know how the Twitter app is written, it's way more fast. Is JSON quicker ?

Comment: Hmm... Good point! I don't know. I had never thought about it and have been so surprised that such a small trick can boost up the speed. But have never tried JSON. However this question here seems to confirm that JSON is faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596465/is-parsing-json-faster-than-parsing-xml